# How to use jquery.scrollTo with jquery(.load) method, loading external pages in the same div

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I am creating POC of the website, its a multi page website,
There are three sections in the index page, and I am loading the external HTML Pages into specific div.
for example:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>    
<div id="footer"></div>
```

and the pages loading via jquery like this:

```
$("#header").load("./pages/header.html");
$("#content").load("./pages/home.html");        
$("#footer").load("./pages/footer.html");
```

On the Home page there are several sections with specific IDs like

When I click on the page2 I need to load page2.html into $("content") div
see below jquery code

```
$(document).on("click", "#home  nav a.page2", function(){               
            $("body").attr("id","page2");
            $("#content").load("pages/page2.html");
            return false;
});
```

Header is same for all pages and when user click on the section 3 or section 4, links in the header its again load the home page and scrollto target section which is not working.

How to solve this issue

Please check the demo on : 
http://kui.link/materialize/

Comment: Do you mean you cannot scroll to the respective section after you load the page2? If yes, how you scroll to the section? I didn't find that information in your question. It would be helpful to understand your question.

Comment: I would like to explain the Issue step by step: 

1) click on the http://kui.link/materialize/

2) On the header click on the Page2 link

3) page2.html has been loaded in the content div

4) while you are on Page2 click on the section3, section4, links on header

5) Now home.html is loaded in the content div, but targeted element scroll not works as expected.

6) Its is expected to go to targeted section by scrolling the page.

7) I am using jquery.ScrollTo plugin for anchor scroll (http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Comment: The scroll to event is being fired before the content is being loaded and so the scroll to position is being calculated wrong. You need some way to identify when the .load event has finished to then trigger the scroll to event.

Comment: I have tried so may ways, but didn't work, If you have small example, then please let me know.

Comment: You could see if the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event is called and simply add an event listener that listens for it, then scrolls to the correct div and removes itself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I found setTimeout function which I used to fix this issue and its works. currently observing how its works in all major browsers.